# CSS3 flip card IE

Tags: css, transform, flip

I have this code:

```
<section class="container">
   <div id="card">
      <figure class="front">front side</figure>
      <figure class="back">back side</figure>
   </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gt99eyun/3/

Works well in chrome, firefox, but not in IE, even newest 10 and 11.

I noticed in IE after flipping to back side, if I turn off

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

for the back side, then it displays properly.

This would be like I do this:

```
#card.flipped .back {
    backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

However this is no good because it happens immediately when flipped class is added.

Can I make this work in IE?